# Setting an SSIS Variable from JAMS Scheduler

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2008

Executing a file system SSIS package through JAMS scheduler. The following code works fine (Execution method of "SSIS"):

```
/f "C:\Path\To\File.dtsx"
```

I'd like to set the value of one of the variables in the package with a parameter on the job. I've seen a few different examples online, none of which work. They center around something similar to this:

```
/f "C:\Path\To\File.dtsx"
/SET "\Package.Variables[User::VariableName].Properties[Value];<<ParameterName>>"
```

I'm guessing I just have the syntax incorrect. Has anyone successfully done this?

*My references are:*

- https://support.jamsscheduler.com/hc/en-us/articles/206894787?page=1
- http://www.sqldbpros.com/2014/10/scheduling-ssis-packages-with-jams-simple-not-easy/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Parameter name in JAMS must match the Variable name in your package. That allowed it to be set correctly.